# Android. ImageButton, stretch background and center src

Tags: android, android-studio, imagebutton, stretch

I have a ImageButton with 2 images

What I need from this imagebutton if having the backgrounf image to stretch, etc the src image to be centered in the stretched button)

- The background image(textured gray) to stretch between 2 ImageButton
- The src image("Title") to be centered on this button.

[image]

Still 2 problems:
1- Background stretch seem to work, but only if I replace layout_width="wrap_content" with layout_width="fill_parent", BUT, the button doesn't from before the other button.
2- even with fill parent, i get the src image also stretched.

Suggestions welcome!

xml:

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Title"
    android:background="@drawable/a_btn_sort_title"
    android:onClick="listView_FilterBy_Title"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number"
android:cropToPadding="true"
android:src="@drawable/a_btn_sort_title_en"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Fav"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer:

1-  ImageButton  between 2 ImageButton = remove: "android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number""

2-  Src centered:   android:scaleType="fitCenter"

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Title"
    android:background="@drawable/a_btn_sort_title"
    android:onClick="listView_FilterBy_Title"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:src="@drawable/a_btn_sort_title_en"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Fav"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnListviewHeader_Number" />
```

Hope it help someone :)